# creating a dictionary by partitioning a dictionary with new keys in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the a dictionary like this:

```
{"Topic":"text","title":"texttitle","abstract":"textabs","year":"textyear","authors":"authors"}
```

I want to create another list as follows:

```
[{"label":{"Topic":"text","title":"texttitle","abstract":"textabs","year":"textyear","authors":"authors"},"value":
{"Topic":"text","title":"texttitle","abstract":"textabs","year":"textyear","authors":"authors"}}]
```

I have tried some methods with .items() but none of them gives the desired result.

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid python.  It looks like a cross between a list and a dictionary?

Comment: _I have tried some methods with .items()_ It would help if you showed us the code you tried, including the results, and explain how that isn't what you wanted.

Comment: @JohnGordon I forgot to add the brackets.added it now.I mean dict.items()

Comment: @Tim I think all you have to do is create a new dictionary to contain the "key" (desired) and value is the dictionary and looping through new keys and dictionary can be created and finally appended into the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
dict_ = {"Topic":"text","title":"texttitle","abstract":"textabs","year":"textyear","authors":"authors"}
output = [{"label": dict_ , "value": dict_ }]
print(output)
```

```
[{"label":{"Topic":"text","title":"texttitle","abstract":"textabs","year":"textyear","authors":"authors"},"value":
{"Topic":"text","title":"texttitle","abstract":"textabs","year":"textyear","authors":"authors"}}] == [{"label": dict_ , "value": dict_ }]
```

Gives `True`

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment, below is the code I would go through assuming key and output:

```
    # Could be the keys would get from somewhere
    vals = ["1","2","3","4"]
    # Probably same coming from external sources
    example_op = 
    {"Topic":"text","title":"texttitle","abstract":"textabs","year":"textyear","authors":"authors"}
    #Global list
    item_list = []
    temp_dict = {}
    for key in vals:
        temp_dict[key] = example_op
    item_list.append(temp_dict)
```

Final output of the list would be as:

```
Out[9]: 
[{'1': {'Topic': 'text',
   'title': 'texttitle',
   'abstract': 'textabs',
   'year': 'textyear',
   'authors': 'authors'},
  '2': {'Topic': 'text',
   'title': 'texttitle',
   'abstract': 'textabs',
   'year': 'textyear',
   'authors': 'authors'},
  '3': {'Topic': 'text',
   'title': 'texttitle',
   'abstract': 'textabs',
   'year': 'textyear',
   'authors': 'authors'},
  '4': {'Topic': 'text',
   'title': 'texttitle',
   'abstract': 'textabs',
   'year': 'textyear',
   'authors': 'authors'}}]
```